# Send video title to VLC in Android

Tags: android, vlc

Is there any way to send video's **Title** with [Intent.putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method? MX Player for example, recognises the putExtra("title", "my video title"); but VLC doesn't and I can't find any documentation about this...

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Perusing the source code would be an obvious step.

Comment: Nice tip about the source, thanks. Would be great if someone posted a link to it, because I can't find the android app project source... Thanks

Comment: As VLC is mostly GPL licensed a binary should come with clear documentation as to how to obtain the source.  If this is a build direct from videolan, have you checked their codebase?